# How to make ajax download multiple files at once/in parallel?

Tags: ajax

I have a json file that is about 1.6MB. This json file will be used in my site's auto-suggest feature; I am using TypeAhead from Twitter.

On slower connections, 1.6MB would take many seconds. So my first solution is to split this file into multiple files, maybe .16MB each.

How can I make ajax call(s) so that the browser each of these files in parallel? Is that doable using ajax?

Comment: One file or 10, you still have to transfer 1.6MB across the wire.  If the first byte of the first file is worthless without the last byte of the last file, then you're better off leaving it as one big file.  Throw up a progress bar or something.

Comment: each file would be a complete file, ie the 1.6MB would contain over 26k records, so if i split the files up each file would contain something like 2.6k records each.

Comment: Most modern browsers will permit about 6 connections in parallel; after that, they queue up the requests and execute them as connections become available.  You can definitely execute multiple ajax calls in rapid succession and assume the browser will run them in parallel.  Make sure you're issuing the (normal) async ajax calls!

Comment: i assume "most modern browsers" does not include <ie9? ill look into this.

Comment: Not sure.  Be sure to look at usage stats such as [Internet Explorer Statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp)